# Superuser or Admin in Cakephp 3 - E-Commerce with Admin

Tags: cakephp, authorization, e-commerce

I'm creating an E-Commerce website using CakePHP 3

I need to create an Admin page that will allow the Admin to upload
products and possibly view a few KPI's etc..

Is there a way in Cake to have a User (general customer shopping on the site) and a Superuser (or Admin) at the same time? I have an 'is_admin' column in my Users table to differentiate between admin and user. Do I just need to have something like this in my addProducts function or **is there a better way?**:

```
public function addProducts(){
    $user = $this->Auth->user();
    if($user['is_admin']) {
        //allow access
    } else {
      //throw anauthorised exception
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can manage it via different URL's for admin and front User. This can be managed via the routes and the APP Controller.
**What I am using for one of my appplication is as below:**

**In the routes.php file**

```
Router::prefix('admin', function ($routes) {
    // All routes here will be prefixed with `/admin`
    // And have the prefix => admin route element added.
    $routes->fallbacks('DashedRoute');
    $routes->connect('/', array('controller' => 'Users', 'action' => 'login'));
    /* Here you can define all the routes for the admin */
});

Router::scope('/', function ($routes) {

    $routes->connect('/', array('controller' => 'Users', 'action' => 'login', 'home'));
    /* Here you can define all the routes for the frontend */
});
```

Please note for the Admin you need to create a directory in all /src/Controller, /src/Template named as "Admin" and within these directories you can use the same structure that we use in our code.

**Now comes the code that needs to be written in /src/Controller/AppController.php**

```
public $prefix = '';
public function initialize()
{

    $this->prefix = (!empty($this->request->params['prefix'])?$this->request->params['prefix']:'');
    $this->set('prefix',$this->prefix);
    if( !empty($this->prefix) && $this->prefix==='admin' )
    {   

        $this->loadComponent('Auth', [

            'loginAction' => [
                'controller' => 'Users',
                'action' => 'login',
                'prefix'=>'admin'
            ],
            'loginRedirect' => [
                'controller' => 'Users',
                'action' => 'index',
                'prefix'=>'admin'
            ],
            'logoutRedirect' => [
                'controller' => 'Users',
                'action' => 'login',
                'prefix'=>'admin'
            ],
            'authError' => 'Did you really think you are allowed to see that?',
            'authenticate' => [
                'Form' => [
                    'finder' => 'admin',
                    'fields' => ['username' => 'email', 'password' => 'password']
                ]
            ],
            'storage' => ['className' => 'Session', 'key' => 'Auth.Admin']
        ]);
    }

    else
    {

        $this->loadComponent('Auth', [

            'loginAction' => [
                'controller' => 'Users',
                'action' => 'login'
            ],
            'loginRedirect' => [
                'controller' => 'Users',
                'action' => 'myaccount'
            ],
            'logoutRedirect' => [
                'controller' => 'Users',
                'action' => 'login'
            ],
            'authError' => 'Did you really think you are allowed to see that?',
            'authenticate' => [
                'Form' => [
                    'finder' => 'user',
                    'fields' => ['username' => 'email', 'password' => 'password']
                ]
            ],
            'storage' => ['className' => 'Session', 'key' => 'Auth.User']
        ]);
    }
}
```

Here you can see that we are using different keys for the storage Auth.User and Auth.Admin

**For the finder you need to write the below code in your user model table located at src\Model\Table\UsersTable.php**

```
public function findAdmin(\Cake\ORM\Query $query, array $options)
{
    $query
        ->select(array('Users.email', 'Users.password','Users.id','Users.role_id'))
        ->where(array('Users.role_id' => 1));

    return $query;
}
public function findUser(\Cake\ORM\Query $query, array $options)
{
    $query
        ->select(array('Users.email', 'Users.password','Users.id','Users.role_id'))
        ->where(array('Users.status' => 1,'Users.role_id' => 3));

    return $query;
}
```

Note, Here I am keeping role_id "1" for Admin and "3" for front Users.

**In this manner, even you can set the login for both in the same browser as key for both the user types is different.**

Hope this helps you setup the structure accordingly.

Comment: https://github.com/dereuromark/cakephp-tinyauth could help you here keeping it a clean config way and with simple roles.